# Company website - devise a custom-built solution or ride on top of an existing service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web, organization

I've been asked to devise a website for a small organization (with limited funding) - with internal and external facing sides.

Internally it would allow sharing of documents, a blog, goal setting, more?

Externally it would provide a simple but nicely designed public statement about the company's services.

It may evolve over time.

Should this be a custom-built solution or does it make more sense to ride on top of a platform that provides this type of service (such as?)?

If it's a custom built-solution, I'm considering doing this in Rails - would there be something like this already built for Rails?

Comment: This is a fairly open-ended question, but would you please mark an answer as acceptable? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I've always found it frustrating to build on top of pre-existing platforms, especially when it comes time to extend the functionality. If it's up to you, I'd suggest to build it yourself. Pick a framework and design specifically around the needs of the company.

Rails is a nice choice if you're comfortable programming Ruby. Although, any modern MVC framework would be just as good.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite a big fan of Hobo. Sits on top of and extends Rails. Provides a lot of standard scaffolding, an admin function and section, and lets you publish static pages. You can stick a "before_filter :login_required" on any and all controllers to prevent random visitors from seeing things, or extend the user model to have role or other based access controls.

I've never used Hobo to fully build out a scaled service for more than a handful of users. But in a small environment, it's awesomely fast to put together resources, with access controls.

Answer (score 0):

[Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) has an amazing admin function already built into the framework. It could potentially take care of all of the internals, and the external view can be shown to anyone who doesn't navigate to the admin.

It's at least one consideration if you're thinking of making a custom solution (which I might suggest if you believe the site will most likely grow.)

Comment: You can do an admin in Rails too. Why learn a new framework just for this?

Comment: You never said you knew Rails, only that you were considering it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your resources, I would start off with an "as-is" solution that allows customization.  This will give you the quickest "wins" from the company standpoint.  Once the organization, and you, start to use and understand the benefits, you can start customizing pieces.

Comment: What's an "as-is" solution? Is this commonly used terminology? I've never heard it before.

Answer (score -2):

Depending on your budget [Windchill](http://www.ptc.com/products/windchill/) does this. I believe it was once called GlobalVault (a much better, and more descriptive, name).

Comment: I should have mentioned (and have edited the question) to indicate this is an organization with very limited funding - just starting up.

Comment: How is that site even remotely relevant? Are you just messing around?

Comment: I couldn't figure out what this site does either but I assume the poster has some experience with them for the purpose I described.

Comment: They produce a product that houses everything that can be stored electronically. ITT Corporation uses GlobalVault to manage its international collaborations. Hardly trolling imo.